# How can i use eclipse as an IDE for j++

Tags: eclipse, debugging, migration, j++

is it possible to debug j++ projects with Eclipse?

Comment: I don't think there is an answer to it in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to, because we do it with Netbeans.
I though don't have enough knowledge of Eclipse to know if this is possible with it.

If anybody is still interested how I did it with Netbeans just ask and I will provide the pretty complex instructions.

The base of the idea is as follows:
First make new ANT project for the project.
Write the build, clean etc tasks to that as ANT still supports VJC (J++) compiler.
Make Netbeans (Or possibly Eclipse) project that can build an existing ANT project.
Now you have the build environment in order.
Add new target to the ide (Not sure if Eclipse supports this) with the J++ class ZIPs.
Now the IDE should be content with references to the MS specific classes.

We have maintained our legacy platform with this kind of setup over a year now.

We had to do some cleaning to our projects because J++ allows some pretty pervers constructions, but it was mostly handled with renaming using the excellent refactoring capabilities of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

No. J++ is a microsoft specific technology that has not been licensed to anyone else. You will need DevStudio to work with j++ source.